# Retrofit and RxJava: Combine Flowable with Observable to get result

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java2

I want to combine a Flowable with an Observable to create a  Model from that sources.

From Room I get CartModel items this models contains an id of product and quantity.

```
  @Override
        public Flowable<List<CartModel>> getCartItems() {
            return appLocalDataStore.getCartItems();
        }
```

After that I have a function  that for every id from above function compose a Pair of quantity and Product Details.

```
@Override
public Observable<List<Pair<WsProductDetails, Integer>>> getCartWithProductData() {
    return appLocalDataStore.getCartItems().toObservable().flatMap(new Function<List<CartModel>, ObservableSource<CartModel>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<CartModel> apply(List<CartModel> cartModels) throws Exception {
            return Observable.fromIterable(cartModels);
        }
    }).flatMap(new Function<CartModel, ObservableSource<Pair<WsProductDetails, Integer>>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<Pair<WsProductDetails, Integer>> apply(final CartModel cartModel) throws Exception {
            return appRemoteDataStore.getProductBySKU(cartModel.getId()).map(new Function<WsProductDetails, Pair<WsProductDetails, Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public Pair<WsProductDetails, Integer> apply(WsProductDetails wsProductDetails) throws Exception {
                    Log.d("TestCartItems", "SKU" + wsProductDetails.getSku() + "  quantity" + cartModel.getQuantity());
                    return new Pair<>(wsProductDetails, cartModel.getQuantity());
                }
            });
        }
    }).toList().toObservable();
}   

 @GET(PATH_PRODUCT_DETAILS_BY_SKY)
    Observable<WsProductDetails> getProductBySKU(@Path(PATH_CODE) String cod);
```

Above function works ok , because the logs are corect.

But in My Presenter OnNext()||OnError()||onComplete() function is never called.
Why this happens?

```
@Override
    public void getCartItems() {
        Observable<List<Pair<WsProductDetails, Integer>>> source = appDataStore.getCartWithProductData();
        mCompositeDisposable.add(source
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<Pair<WsProductDetails, Integer>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete()");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Pair<WsProductDetails, Integer>> pairs) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onError()");
                        view.showCartItems(pairs);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onError()");
                    }
                }));

    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK Room returns infinite `Flowable`s and you are using `toList` as well which requires a finite source. Try `getCartItems().take(1)`.

Comment: @akarnokd thanks for your response this works but emit only first element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply the lookup flatMap to the inner fromIterable so it gets finite:

```
@Override
public Observable<List<Pair<WsProductDetails, Integer>>> getCartWithProductData() {
    return appLocalDataStore.getCartItems().toObservable().flatMap(new Function<List<CartModel>, ObservableSource<CartModel>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<CartModel> apply(List<CartModel> cartModels) throws Exception {
            return Observable.fromIterable(cartModels)
                .flatMap(new Function<CartModel, ObservableSource<Pair<WsProductDetails, Integer>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableSource<Pair<WsProductDetails, Integer>> apply(final CartModel cartModel) throws Exception {
                        return appRemoteDataStore.getProductBySKU(cartModel.getId())
                            .map(new Function<WsProductDetails, Pair<WsProductDetails, Integer>>() {
                             @Override
                             public Pair<WsProductDetails, Integer> apply(WsProductDetails wsProductDetails) throws Exception {
                                 Log.d("TestCartItems", "SKU" + wsProductDetails.getSku() + "  quantity" + cartModel.getQuantity());
                                 return new Pair<>(wsProductDetails, cartModel.getQuantity());
                             }
                         });
                     }
                }).toList().toObservable();
        }
    });
}
```